# Erlang 17 HTTP SOAP service

Tags: soap, erlang, erlang-otp

I am new in Erlang and I want to make http soap service.

I have linux-base distributive with 17 OTP version:
(Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V6.0)

I need recommends, what framework to use, or what kind of libraries I can use to implement this service. 
Thanks to all

Answer (score 2):

Bet365 have open-sourced their SOAP libraries earlier this year: https://github.com/bet365/soap -- there's a decent amount of documentation there to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

[Erlsom](https://github.com/willemdj/erlsom) with [Yaws](http://yaws.hyber.org/) is worth looking at. Although Erlsom is an XML library, there is a SOAP example included in the Erlsom source tree.